# Visualize a dataframe with same column names, represent each column with different colors in R

Tags: r, visualization

I am trying to visualize a dataframe, which is a result of sampling variation.

| class | Data | Data | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Car | 3.4 | 1.2 | 90 |
| Bike | 3.6 | 2.4 | 89 |
| Cycle | 4.2 | 1.5 | 78 |

As you can see the column has the same name data, I want to visualize a line graph marking these points and for each column I need a different colour.

```
ggplot(tab7, aes(class,data)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(data~ .)
```

I am getting an error as below:

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

Comment: `ggplot` is designed to work with "long" (aka tidy, aka "3rd normal form" in CS) data. So your first step should be to reshape the three "Data" columns, e.g. by using `tidyr::pivot_longer()`.

Comment: @JonSpring You mean that class should be the column and data should be in rows?

Comment: I am trying to use this code here to pivot longer:
tab7 %>% pivot_longer(!class , names_to = "data", values_to = "count"), I get an error as below

Error in `[.data.frame`(data, unique(names(data))) : undefined columns selected

Comment: You might want `pivot_longer(-class, ....)` to mean pivot all the columns that aren't `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're looking for, but it seems to be something like this:

```
tab7 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-class) %>% 
  select(class, value) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value, class)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = class))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, This is the kind of visualization I wanted to do, but also add a line on it.

Comment: What is values here in the code?

Comment: `value` represents all of the `data` columns from the example you provided.

Comment: You can run `tab7 %>% pivot_longer(-class)` to inspect it

Comment: @KevinJ, happy to help! you can accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark - it will also let others know that the question is answered.